# Turn off a specific USB Port when Screen is turned off

Tags: usb, port

I have been using a USB LED light in my laptop (Windows 10), and I remotely control the OS via my Android phone. Although I can run every command from the phone, I have to physically disconnect the USB LED light every time. Is there a way (registry edit or software) to Turn Off this specific USB Port, *ideally when the Screen is Turned Off*.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is not possible. You could try though tools like IntelliAdmin USB disabler (http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/usb-disabler-pro/) but I don't think this will be a solution for you since you want to control the 5V power supply of a specific USB port and most of those DLP solutions who block USB ports block it on software level in order to still support mice and other equipment to work while they disable the use of mass storage etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yeah I don't think that will do the trick. I checked some videos online on how to manually Enable/Disable a specific USB port using CMD, however I am not sure how safe this process is.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, this is not possible.

When a computer is powered on, USB ports are always supplied power so that peripherals such as mice and keyboards work.  Even in a sleep state, the ports are powered so USB devices such as a keyboard or mouse can wake the computer from sleep.  There are even USB ports (typically colored yellow), called "sleep and charge" ports which will provide power even when the computer is turned off.

However, this *is* possible if your USB hub supports per-port power switching.  Unfortunately, the odds of the USB hub in your laptop supporting this feature is basically zero.  I have never seen or heard of this feature built into a consumer computer, only in a few (expensive) external USB hubs.

Comment: @George if you found this to be useful and the correct answer, you should upvote and mark it as the answer for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some programmable relay connected to USB port. The relay will allow to set 5V from USB port, or 0V.
As an example : DSD TECH SH-UR01A USB Relay Controller for Computers and Laptops (1CH) which costs about 20 $.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).